# IE 9 Security Warning for Facebook - Related Files When Viewing Page Tab

Tags: ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I have a page tab app. The site that has my app hosted has SSL enabled. When I view the page tab using IE9 I get an insecure content error and in my console I can see:

```
HTTPS security is compromised by http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=11
```

this is only when I view the page tab using regular http protocol e.g:

```
http://www.facebook.com/mypage/myapp
```

if I am viewing Facebook securely it does not happen, e.g:

```
https://www.facebook.com/mypage/myapp
```

The app uses the JavaScript SDK but I am doing things to ensure it uses the secure version such as:

```
FB._https = true;
```

before

```
FB.init()
```

when I link to the SDK I am sure I am using the secure connection:

```
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
```

I do **not** get these errors if I view the pages directly on my server , it only happens when viewed inside of the page tab. I'm thinking that Facebook is generating this call to unsecure resources. I've done allot of searching but can't find a way to fix this. Could anyone recommend a way to deal with this? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!